# Magento: Grab/Display Customer's Lifetime Sales Stats and Total Amount of Orders on Order View Pages

Tags: magento, statistics, account, lifetime

In the Order View (the main screen when viewing a customer's order), I would like to add a few table rows and add the Customer's Lifetime Sales (Total Sales) and Total Amount of Orders.

The file I want to add the code is here: app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml

In this file, below:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getCustomerAccountData() as $data):?>
  <tr>
    <td class="label"><label><?php echo $data['label'] ?></label></td>
    <td class="value"><strong><?php echo $data['value'] ?></strong></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Is where I'd add my the rows/cells I need with the correct information. Could you please tell me how to get the necessary data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is how you get the lifetime sales:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
$customerTotals = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/sale_collection')
     ->setOrderStateFilter(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true)
     ->setCustomerFilter($customer)
     ->load()
     ->getTotals();
$customerLifetimeSales = $customerTotals->getLifetime();
$customerNumberOfOrders = $customerTotals->getNumOrders();
```

This is a var_dump of $customerTotals:

```
object(Varien_Object)[662]
  protected '_data' => 
    array
     'lifetime' => float 10503.13
     'base_lifetime' => float 10503.13
     'base_avgsale' => float 92.9480530973
     'num_orders' => int 113
     'avgsale' => float 92.9480530973
  protected '_hasDataChanges' => boolean false
  protected '_origData' => null
  protected '_idFieldName' => null
  protected '_isDeleted' => boolean false
```

You can place that code in a method on your block and call it in each row. Somthing like:

```
public function getCustomerTotals(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer)
{
    // TODO: Add necessary validation...
    return Mage::getResourceModel('sales/sale_collection')
        ->setOrderStateFilter(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true)
        ->setCustomerFilter($customer)
        ->load()
        ->getTotals();
}
```

and in your code there you can add:

```
<?php $customerTotals = $this->getCustomerTotals($customer); ?>
<td><?php echo $customerTotals->getLifetime(); ?></td>
```

Comment: I will have to give this a try soon! This 'project' went on the backburner for now but if this works that's one thing off the list!

Comment: I finally ended up using this in a module for adding it to the order overview page (with a little modification). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it's due to an upgrade, but now it's necessary to add this:

```
->setOrderStateFilter(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true)
```

So, the code will be:

```
return Mage::getResourceModel('sales/sale_collection')
        ->setOrderStateFilter(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true)
        ->setCustomerFilter($customer)
        ->load()
        ->getTotals();
```

Comment: Thank you for adding this otherwise the data would have been wrong (or at least not the same as in the customer account).